# Add a default item to a stream collection

Tags: java, java-8

I am performing some actions on a stream and returning an array list.  This is working without a problem but I need to do a final step to add an element if the array list is empty (nothing to do with options / nulls just part of the requirement)  My way is a bit clunky and I wondered if it can be done in the stream operation instead?

```
public ArrayList<String> getArrayList () {

        ArrayList<String> aL =  setOfStrings.stream()
            .filter(remove some)
            .filter(remove some more)
            .map(i -> createStringAbout(i))
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));

        if (aL.size() < 1) {
            aL.add("No items passed the test");
        }

        return aL;
    }
```

So really I would like to do

```
return set.stream()...
```

is this possible ?

Comment: there is no way to reliable tell the size of the Stream... what you have in place is as clean as it can get IMO

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `collectingAndThen`

```
.collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(ArrayList::new, rs -> {
                    if(rs.size() < 1 ) {
                        rs.add("something");
                    }
                   return rs;
                })
```

Comment: [`Collectors.toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--): “*There are no guarantees on the type, **mutability**, serializability, or thread-safety of the List returned*”; this implies that you can not assume that you can `add` another element. Besides that, `rs.size() < 1` can be simplified to `rs.isEmpty()`…

Comment: sorry if I'm asking to be spoon fed here but  
       ...
            .map(i -> createStringAbout(i))
            .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen (Collectors.toList(), lst -> {
             if(lst.size() < 1) {
              lst.add("there is nothing to say");
             }
            }));
doesn't seem to work.  I get errors on CollectingAndThen (type collectors is not applicable for the arguments) and also on size & add.- it doesn't seem to take lst as a List ?  I've tried perusing the web and I can't seem to 'get it' ?

Comment: @gringogordo there's a `return rs` missing after the `if` block. Besides, Holger is right: you need to do `Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)` instead of `Collectors.toList()`

Comment: Thanks that was a real education!  For posterity using the answer and comments above I got the following working version... ... .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new), 
            lst -> {
             if(lst.size() < 1) {
              lst.add("No items passed the test");
             }
       return lst;
            }));